# Study the convergence of this sequence in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $x_{n}$ be a seuquence in $\mathbb{R}$, define the sequence of functions:
$$u_{n}=\chi_{B(x_{n},1)}$$
where $\chi$ denotes the characteristic function. Study the convergence of $u_{n}\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ in the strong topology and weak topology in the following cases cases:

a) $x_{n}\longrightarrow0$

b)$|x_{n}|\longrightarrow+\infty$

The first case should be the easier, since we expect the limit to be $0$, if it exists. So we may compute:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\chi_{B(x_{n},1)})^{2}dx=\int_{x_{n}-1}^{x_{n}+1}dx=2$$
Thus there can't be strong convergence. Regarding weak convergence, we know
$$u_{n}\rightharpoonup0\iff\int_{\mathbb{R}}u_{n}\varphi dx\longrightarrow0\quad\forall\varphi\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})
$$
so why not $\varphi=u_{n}$ again. Then we would have $u_{n}$ doesn't converge weakly in this case.
Does this idea work? Am I missing something? Does case $b)$ follow similarly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in the first case where $x_n\to 0,$ you should expect strong convergence to $\chi_{B(0,1)}.$ In the second case, how about weak convergence to $0$ and no strong convergence?